# Why do I keep getting this pop-up in Visual Studio ( "File has been modified outside of the source editor)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This might be a really easy question, but it's drivin me insane.. so , In Visual studio 2012, while editing code, I keep getting:

```
"File has been modified outside of the source editor. Do you want to reload it"
```

[image]

But I don't even remember editing anything? Could SVN change that? (i.e if the code is shared in SVN, if someone else changes sxomething, then it queries me for that? )

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same issue. I also lost IntelliSense and class/interface/attributes are not colored. The project builds, so I don't know what's up with that

Comment: @programmer93 - No, but it's safe to say "Yes to all" -  boss said that

Comment: Mine had something to do with a plugin I installed. Took me forever to realize that though.

Comment: I installed Strip'em and this kept popping every time I save a file.